# Splitting a single string to an array on more than one delimiter

Tags: php, explode, preg-split

Is it possible to explode the following:

`08 1.2/3(1(1)2.1-1`

to an array of `{08, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1}`?

I tried using `preg_split("/ (\s|\.|\-|\(|\)) /g", '08 1.2/3(1(1)2.1-1')` but it returned nothing. I tried checking my regex [here](https://regex101.com/) and it matched well. What am I missing here?

Comment: You have spaces either side of your regex that shouldn't be there. Try `/(\s|\.|\-|\(|\)|\/)/`

Comment: @Nick Is the flag `g` by default?

Comment: yes, you don't need `g` for `preg_split`

Comment: @Nick Oh my god, it did work just by erasing the space. Is that the correct syntax? Even a space can cause error?

Comment: If you put a space (or any character) in the regex, then it has to match something.

Comment: The character class approach in @RicardoOrtegaMagaña answer is a cleaner way to do it than the alternations you are doing.

Comment: @Nick I see, so it interpreted my regex as requiring a space on both sides of the delimiters? Also, why is it cleaner?

Comment: Yes, that's it exactly. His regex is a lot easier to read than yours...

Comment: @Nick I see, thank you! First time creating regex here xD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a *character class* containing all the delimiters which you want to use for splitting.  Regex character classes appear inside `[...]`:

```
<?php
$keywords = preg_split("/[\s,\/().-]+/", '08 1.2/3(1(1)2.1-1');
print_r($keywords);
```

Result:

```
Array ( [0] => 08 [1] => 1 [2] => 2 [3] => 3 [4] => 1 [5] => 1 [6] => 2 [7] => 1 [8] => 1 )
```

Comment: Why didn't mine work? What did I do wrong in my example?

Comment: @RichardW you have spaces either side of your regex that shouldn't be there.

Comment: @RichardW You need a regex character class, see my comment.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I see, so a character class basically contains all the things I want to be part of my regex selection, that way, I don't have to use `|` repeatedly?

Comment: @RichardW Yup.  I agree with your comment.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It also seems like I don't need `g` to apply the flag. SAY though I want to apply some flags to my regex, do I just place the flag character(s) at the back of the regex as in https://regex101.com/?

Comment: @RichardW Please ask a new question if you have lingering doubts on regex.  Not nice to start a discussion festival here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Okay, thank you for the reminder and the answers :-D

Answer (score 0):

You can use preg_match_all():

```
$str = '08 1.2/3(1(1)2.1-1';
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't mean only digits, I only want to delimit based on those delimiters only. Other things can pass through as the element of the array.